# Convert value from text field to paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fill forms and generate an email from that, but on big scale. HTML code is bellow and located on https://jsfiddle.net/csq7kwmb/4/:

```
<form class="form">
    <label>Merchant name <input type="text" class="mName" value=""></label><br>
    <label>Merchant ID number <input type="text" class="mId" value=""></label><br>
    <label>Merchant email <input type="text" class="mEmail" value=""></label><br>
    <button onclick="generateEmail()">
      Generate
    </button>
</form>
<p class="paragraph">
    Merchant name is <span class="merchantN"></span>, merchant ID is <span class="merchantID"></span> and his email is <span class="merchantE"></span>.
</p>
```

```
function generateEmail() {
  //generated email variable
  var email = document.querySelector('.paragraph');

  //input
  var merchantName = document.querySelector('.mName');
  var merchantId = document.querySelector('.mId');
  var merchantEmail = document.querySelector('.mEmail');

  //output
  var paragraphName = document.querySelector('.merchantN');
  var paragraphId = document.querySelector('.merchantID');
  var paragraphEmail = document.querySelector('.merchantE');
  //var paragraph = document.getElementById('field2');

  //properly filled email
  paragraphName.textContent = merchantName.value;
  paragraphId.textContent = merchantId.value;
  paragraphEmail.textContent = merchantEmail.value;

  //displaying email, giding text fields
  merchantName.style.display = none;
  merchantId.style.display = none;
  merchantEmail.style.display = none;
  email.style.display = block;
}
```

The page, when i do that locally, only refreshes.

Comment: Like using `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`? Oh Just kidding, I see what you mean now. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is because you have a `<button>` inside of a `<form>` element, when you click the button, the form is performing its submit action and this causes the page to refresh. What you will need to do is to prevent your form from being submitted or place your button outside of the form.

#### Button outside form:

```html
<form class="form">
  <label>Merchant name <input type="text" class="mName"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant ID number <input type="text" class="mId"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant email <input type="text" class="mEmail"></label><br>
</form>
    <button onclick="generateEmail()">
  Generate
  </button>
<p class="paragraph">
  Merchant nname is <span class="merchantN"></span>, merchant ID is <span class="merchantID"></span> and his email is <span class="merchantE"></span>.
</p>
```

#### Prevent form submit:

```html
<form class="form" onsubmit="return false;">
  <label>Merchant name <input type="text" class="mName"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant ID number <input type="text" class="mId"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant email <input type="text" class="mEmail"></label><br>
    <button onclick="generateEmail()">
  Generate
  </button>
</form>
<p class="paragraph">
  Merchant nname is <span class="merchantN"></span>, merchant ID is <span class="merchantID"></span> and his email is <span class="merchantE"></span>.
</p>
```

Comment: Still the same, but no longer refreshing. Have you checked js fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/csq7kwmb/4/

Comment: Your JS fiddle doesn't work. The Javascript is not being added to your page. Here's a working fiddle with my code above with [Prevent Submit method](https://jsfiddle.net/et2rcujs/) and [button outside form.](https://jsfiddle.net/et2rcujs/1/) You also had a few JavaScript errors that I fixed.

Comment: Perfect. This is working. However, i have another question, If for example, i have a form for 3 different emails, how to make them work as well?

Comment: Like 3 different email inputs? Use an HTML `id` tag for example `<input id="email1"/>` and then access it in Javascript with `document.getElemenyById('email1')`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as mentioned by R10t, you need to move the button out of the form to avoid redirecting.

Second, if you open the browser console, you will see the following error once you click Generate:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: generateEmail is not defined`

This is related to the setup of your jsFiddle: in the JavaScript section click on **JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)** and change the **LOAD TYPE** to `No wrap - bottom of <head>`

Third, you need quotes around `none` and `block`:

```
//displaying email, giding text fields
merchantName.style.display = 'none';
merchantId.style.display = 'none';
merchantEmail.style.display = 'none';
email.style.display = 'block';
```

Working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ajdc8ypf/3/

```js
function generateEmail() {
  //generated email variable
  var email = document.querySelector('.paragraph');
  
  //input
  var merchantName = document.querySelector('.mName');
  var merchantId = document.querySelector('.mId');
  var merchantEmail = document.querySelector('.mEmail');
  
  //output
  var paragraphName = document.querySelector('.merchantN');
  var paragraphId = document.querySelector('.merchantID');
  var paragraphEmail = document.querySelector('.merchantE');
  //var paragraph = document.getElementById('field2');
  
  //properly filled email
  paragraphName.textContent = merchantName.value;
  paragraphId.textContent = merchantId.value;
  paragraphEmail.textContent = merchantEmail.value;
  
  //displaying email, giding text fields
  merchantName.style.display = 'none';
  merchantId.style.display = 'none';
  merchantEmail.style.display = 'none';
  email.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.paragraph{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label>Merchant name <input type="text" class="mName"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant ID number <input type="text" class="mId"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant email <input type="text" class="mEmail"></label><br>
</form>
<button onclick="generateEmail()">
  Generate
</button>
<p class="paragraph">
  Merchant nname is <span class="merchantN"></span>, merchant ID is <span class="merchantID"></span> and his email is <span class="merchantE"></span>.
</p>
```

**UPD:** If you want to use one JS function for many forms, you could pass the form number / id as a parameter and then query the form you need based on it. Take a look at this example:

```js
function generateEmail(formNumber) {
  //generated email variable
  var email = document.querySelector('#paragraph' + formNumber);
  
  //input
  var merchantName = document.querySelector('#form' + formNumber + ' .mName');
  var merchantId = document.querySelector('#form' + formNumber + ' .mId');
  var merchantEmail = document.querySelector('#form' + formNumber + ' .mEmail');
  
  //output
  var paragraphName = document.querySelector('#paragraph' + formNumber + ' .merchantN');
  var paragraphId = document.querySelector('#paragraph' + formNumber + ' .merchantID');
  var paragraphEmail = document.querySelector('#paragraph' + formNumber + ' .merchantE');
  
  //properly filled email
  paragraphName.textContent = merchantName.value;
  paragraphId.textContent = merchantId.value;
  paragraphEmail.textContent = merchantEmail.value;
  
  //displaying email, giding text fields
  merchantName.style.display = 'none';
  merchantId.style.display = 'none';
  merchantEmail.style.display = 'none';
  email.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.paragraph{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
FORM 1:
<br>
<form class="form" id="form1">
  <label>Merchant name <input type="text" class="mName"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant ID number <input type="text" class="mId"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant email <input type="text" class="mEmail"></label><br>
</form>
<button onclick="generateEmail(1)">
  Generate
</button>
<p id="paragraph1">
  Merchant nname is <span class="merchantN"></span>, merchant ID is <span class="merchantID"></span> and his email is <span class="merchantE"></span>.
</p>
<br>
FORM 2:
<br>
<form class="form" id="form2">
  <label>Merchant name <input type="text" class="mName"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant ID number <input type="text" class="mId"></label><br>
  <label>Merchant email <input type="text" class="mEmail"></label><br>
</form>
<button onclick="generateEmail(2)">
  Generate
</button>
<p id="paragraph2">
  Merchant nname is <span class="merchantN"></span>, merchant ID is <span class="merchantID"></span> and his email is <span class="merchantE"></span>.
</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you :). This will be AWESOME. I just have to figure out how to use this code on like 50 different emails, but not to repeat myself

Comment: You mean that you need to generate 50 emails or to create 50 similar forms? @GoranSovilj

Comment: This is the idea: I have 30, 40, 50 different forms and generate buttons and each form has different email with different things to populate. One is email, for example, for decline, one is for notification, one is for approval, one is just for hey, whats up. All have different text and forms.

Comment: @GoranSovilj you could use the same function and pass the form number as a parameter, check the updated example

Comment: Perfect, that works great. I'll just have to try and make some mods so it does one more thing. THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR ASSISTANCE :). I'm still learning, but you have to start from something, right? :)